# Get access_token programmatically with php

Tags: php, python, rest, curl, cookies

I have a login and password to connect to a platform. After login from browser I will get an access_token it's stored in cookie (I guess). How to get the access token programmatically using PHP (maybe using cURL) ?

I found a solution but it's written in python, how to do the same with PHP ?

Here is the solution with python

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import json
import logging


class GISTokenGenerator:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj))
        self.email = email
        self.login_data = urllib.urlencode({'user[email]': email, 'user[password]': password})

    def generate_token(self):
        logging.info('Generating a token for {0}...'.format(self.email))
        self.opener.open('https://site/users/sign_in', self.login_data)
        for cookie in self.cj:
            if cookie.name == 'aiesec_token':
                token_json = json.loads(urllib.unquote(cookie.value))
                token = token_json['token']['access_token']
        if token is None:
            raise Exception('Unable to generate a token for {0}!'.format(self.email))
        return token
```

Comment: If the access token is stored in a cookie (you sound unsure about this — is it? Can you check?), why are you using cURL to access the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

PHP can access cookies via the superglobal variable `$_COOKIE`. To retrieve a specific cookie, `echo $_COOKIE['name_of_cookie'];`. To access all cookies, loop through them all

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $cookie) {
    echo $cookie;
}
```

#### Edit

As I understand it, once your receive this cookie (presumable called `access_token`), you want to cURL a page with this cookie.

[This](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch11_04.htm) is a pretty good resource on how to fetch a URL with cookies. Essentially,

```
$c = curl_init('http://www.example.com/needs-cookies.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'access_token=' . $_COOKIE['access_token']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Thank you, it make sens for me now how to access the token stored in cookie, but what about the login it self how to login like  `self.opener.open('https://auth.aiesec.org/users/sign_in', self.login_data)`  with PHP I have the login and password

Comment: Now: I connect via html form with login & password => I get an access token stored in cookie.

I want: login (with my login and pass) with a php script (not a web browser) and get the stored token in cookie